# Javascript confirm box redirect to dynamic URL

Tags: php, javascript

This is what I am trying to do, but it does not work. Any solutions?

```
window.location = "delete.php?case=<?php echo $case; ?>"
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you want to accomplish. As it is, your question makes no sense.. to me at least :)

Comment: You need to provide more than that one line of code, and a real question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To handle a redirect when confirming, you need to be sure you use the right quotes at the right time and in the case of a link, make sure to cancel the default link behaviour:

**Inline:**

```html
<a href="#" 
onclick="if (confirm('Delete?')) 
  window.location='delete.php?case=<?php echo $case; ?>'; 
   return false">Delete using script</a>
```

---

**Inline using a Plain JS function:**

```js
function deleteIt(id) {
  if (confirm('Delete?')) {
    window.location='delete.php?case='+id; 
  }
  return false;
}
```

Using

```html
<a href="#" 
onclick="return deleteIt('<?php echo $case; ?>')">Delete using script</a>
```

---

**Unobtrusively using a plain JS function:**

```js
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("<?php echo $case; ?>").onclick=function() {
    if (confirm('Delete?')) {
      window.location='delete.php?case='+this.id; 
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Using

```
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $case; ?>">Delete using script</a>
```

---

**Unobtrusively using jQuery:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#<?php echo $case; ?>").on)"click",function() {
    if (confirm('Delete?')) {
      window.location='delete.php?case='+this.id; 
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Using

```
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $case; ?>">Delete using script</a>
```